# Installing python through pecl - how do I "specify path to Python distribution files"?

Tags: linux, debian, php, python, pecl

I have found several instances where this question has been asked, but **never** answered. This is the part where the installation goes wrong

```
checking for Python files in default path... not found
configure: error: Please specify path to Python distribution files
ERROR: `/tmp/pear/temp/python/configure' failed
```

I find it slightly retarded that it asks me to specify a path, but doesn't tell me how. Also I'm working under the assumption that "path to Python distributed files" is `/usr/local/lib/python2.6/dist-packages`.

How do I specify that path in the command `pecl install -f python` (I had to add the `-f` because otherwise it refused to install an alpha package)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

For everyone's information, I've given up on this. Combining PHP and Python can apparently only be done by CLI.

Answer (score 1):

The PECL python package hasn't been updated in over 3 years and it is still in alpha in the last release. What that error is resulting from is a hardcoded test in the config files that looks for Python.h in /usr/include/python2.5/ and /usr/local/include/python2.5/. You can remedy this by installing the 2.5 dev package:

```
apt-get install python2.5-dev
```

It still didn't compile completely for me, though. There are errors in the PECL python package's python_handlers.c which fail to complete when pecl runs make.